# Android Animate gallery to next image on button click

Tags: android, animation, gallery

I want gallery images to animate back and forth when a button is clicked. I have used setSelection method but it just scrolls to next and previous items without any animation. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bug on the Android Gallery with is Deprecated. I used to simulate a user Fling to achieve animation.

```
int currentPosition = gal.getSelectedItemPosition();
    gallery.setSelection(currentPosition + 1);
    gallery.onFling(null, null, (float) (currentPosition + 1) * 1000, 0);
```